# AX Order header types matching Order Line types

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to override the behaviour of MS Dynamics Connector by allowing synchronised orders to be modified in CRM 2011 and be sent back updated to AX 2012.

The problem is that when I update a record in CRM the update does not get written in AX.
The error I get is:

Discrepancy in order type between order line and order header

But when I check at them:
Order type is Sales Order
Order status is Open Order

Line Status is Open Order
Line Type is Sales Order

Those are also the values that I am sending from the connector.

Is there some internal logic in AX that I am missing?
What would be the ideal status that would match both the header and the orde rline?

Comment: how do you know that is the order type? because you set it or because you debugged it? I'm guessing it is not! show some code & debug output.

Comment: I got it in the AX exception log. There is no code to debug, it's only the connector execution

Answer (score 0):

The error is generated in line 5 of table method `SalesLine.checkSalesType`.

The `SalesType` order line field should match the same field in the `SalesTable` table. Also the sales order must exist.

Comment: Hey Jan. Is the type a string value or an Enum (integer)? Which are the possible values for the field?

Comment: Don't you have developer access to AX? It is an enum, value 3 will give you a normal sales order.